# spx created but needs it to be dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have creaed this spx but i need it to be dynamic, dynamic in the sense is that it should accept

tablename
columns
orderby columns

so i can make this spx to work globally accross all tables, just to say here i am not sending the pk of the tabl whose entry i will be remooving

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spx_DeleteDuplicates]
AS
BEGIN
  WITH DupsNumbered
    AS (
    SELECT [columns List],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [columns List] ORDER BY [orderList]) AS rn
    FROM [table]
    )
    DELETE DupsNumbered
    WHERE rn > 1;
END
```

all the items you see in `[]` needs to be dynamic, how can i make it dynamic

Comment: by making it a dynamic query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a huge supporter of dynamic SQL, but if you must

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spx_DeleteDuplicates] (@TableName varchar(100),@ColumnList varchar(max),@OrderList varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @SQL varchar(max)='
      WITH DupsNumbered
        AS (
        SELECT [ColumnsList],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ColumnsList] ORDER BY [OrderList]) AS rn
        FROM [TableName]
        )
        DELETE DupsNumbered
        WHERE rn > 1;
    '
    Set @SQL=Replace(@SQL,'[TableName]'  ,@TableName)
    Set @SQL=Replace(@SQL,'[ColumnsList]',@ColumnList)
    Set @SQL=Replace(@SQL,'[OrderList]'  ,@OrderList)
    Exec(@SQL)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If your rows are completely duplicate I'd keep it simple :

```
    Select distinct *
    Into #temptable
    From [table] ;

    Truncate table [table];

    Select *
    Into [table] 
    From #temptable
```